# Basic usage of Google Analytics Plugin for Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get analytics from a ***mobile app*** developed in ***Unity3D*** using **[Google Analytics Plugin for Unity](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v4/devguide)**. I've tried the simplest program, it doesn't throw errors but 48 hours later there's no data in Google Analytics dashboards. Here's the complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public GoogleAnalyticsV4 ga;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text myText;
    private void Start() {
        try {
            ga.StartSession();
            ga.LogScreen("MAIN_SCREEN");
            myText.text = $"<b>No errors</b>";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            myText.text = $"<b>{e}</b>";
        }
    }
}
```

If there's a more suitable option than the **[Google Analytics Plugin for Unity](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v4/devguide)** it would be great to know it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the error. In google analytics for Unity3D you must have a [**Universal analytics property**](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10220206) (**UA-XXXXXXX-1**) I always tried it without it and, obviously, it didn't work.

Once you has the [object properly initialized in your inspector](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v4/devguide?hl=es-419), you need to create your script to call analytics functions. I don't know if always is needed but I have to call other function in addition to startSession. As the code I pasted in the question I also called a LogScreen and then I started to recieve information in my GoogleAnalytics.

```
ga.StartSession();
ga.LogScreen("MAIN_SCREEN");
```

**If someone has the same issue I leave here the support page where indicates [how get an Universal Analytics property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10269537)**